# Sets of Roots and Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots

Suppose ${a,b,c,x}\in \Bbb F$. I will call the set $\{a,b,c\}$ the roots, and $\{x\}$ the variable.

We can make a polynomial by multiplying $(x+a)(x+b)$, which works out to be $x^2 + (a+b)x + ab$.

Now consider $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$.
That works out to $x^3 + (a+b+c)x^2 + (ab+ca+cb)x + abc$

I noticed a pattern: The coefficient of the highest order term is always $1$.  For each coefficient after that, select all the subsets of the roots whose length is the degree of the polynomial minus the degree of the term.  Multiply each subset to get a number, then add those numbers together to get the coefficient.

I have confirmed this on paper for polynomials up to degree $4$.  I am guessing the pattern keeps going.

Question:  What theorem proves or disproves this pattern for polynomials of arbitrary degree?

Comment: Cf. [Vieta’s formulas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)

Comment: I see.  This is basically a special case of Vieta's formulas.  I hadn't heard of that before.  Book recommendations are always appreciated.